# Eclipse deletes java files on build of an android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an interesting problem. I pull down an android project from cvs, which works fine.  Once Eclipse builds the project, my .java files are removed.  XML files, pngs, everything else is fine. I seem to be left with just the package tree, but no source files.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Tried unchecking "Delete all not working code"? :D Just kidding, I will reply in a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Right click on the project
- Properties
- Java Build path
- Source

Check that the src folder path is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Not quite sure how I missed that.  The /gen folder was missing.